# In weblogic.xml, <prefer-application-packages> is not working?

Tags: java, weblogic, tomcat8, weblogic12c, opensaml

I have tried a lot of solutions/ try and error which I got from stackover flow and through googling. Using Weblogic 12.2.1.3 and my project **weblogic.xml**

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

      <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <principal-name>Administrators</principal-name>
     </security-role-assignment>

     <wls:container-descriptor>
      <wls:prefer-application-packages>
           <wls:package-name>org.opensaml</wls:package-name>
      </wls:prefer-application-packages>

      <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>

    </wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

The issue is, even I mentioned in weblogic.xml about **opensaml** that take from my project, then also Server is taking from Oracle weblogic. It is not taking from my project. I am using 2.6.6 version of opensaml jar for my project. I have tried with `<wls:package-name>org.opensaml.*</wls:package-name>` but no success.

The main reason to check weblogic.xml is that when I tried to open one specific url it is showing following error in the browser. But it works for **Tomcat** server when you open the same url. So my assumption is weblogic.xml --> prefer-application-packages tag is not working.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1038)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:72)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap.postProcessBeanFactory(SAMLBootstrap.java:42)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:179)
```

Answer (score 0):

Work Around:

> When you delete com.oracle.weblogic.security.opensaml2 from
>   weblogic-->Module folder, the issue get fix. No need to delete
>   com.oracle.weblogic.security.opensaml jar.